# How i can get the URL?

Tags: functions, urls

How i can get the base URL in the wordpress? `get_bloginfo('url')` returns me the current URL. I just want the base URL e.g `http://localhost/wpsite/` not any **?page_id=123** with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use site_url

`<?php echo site_url(); ?>`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url

Or get_site_url

`<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url

Or even home_url

`<?php echo home_url(); ?>`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

which returns the home URL for the site.

***Check the doc links for differences in available parameters.***

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`site_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) or [`home_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url)

Comment: You might get upvotes if you explain the difference and when to use which function.